# How to login without leaving RP by showing the OP login window in iframe?

Tags: iframe, authentication, openid

How to login without leaving RP by showing the OP login window in iframe ?

I am using Openid Provider for the login in my Website.

how to implement the login window inside the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Using an iframe is *hugely* frowned upon, since the user will be entering their credentials on a page that *looks* like it is your RP but is supposedly their OP instead.  It teaches users to be phished.

If you're going to use an iframe anyway, very little special work has to be done.  There are a few approaches you can take though.  If you're taking the OpenID Identifier from the user on the page and will display an iframe based on the user input, then the easiest way is probably to use JavaScript when the user clicks "Login" to create an iframe and direct it at http://yoursite.com/redirect.aspx?openid=*userSuppliedIdentifier*.  That page will perform OpenID discovery on the identifier and do the standard redirect to the OP, which will be limited to the iframe since that is where the request came from.  The openid.return_to that you send to the OP will have to be to a special page that knows how to "pop out" of the iframe back into your main window.  It's really a very similar flow to the popup window approach which I point you to a demo to below, but instead of a popup, you do it in an iframe.

Rather than an iframe, the recommended way if you don't want to send the users away momentarily from your site, is to use a popup window.  Just one such example of this is [DotNetOpenAuth's ajax login sample](http://dotnetopenauth.net/samples/v3.0/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/ajaxlogin.aspx), but there are other ways to do it.  It's always complicated to get it working across browsers and working securely.  We'd need to know what web platform you're using (ASP.NET, PHP, Perl, Python, etc.) before going much further.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET. Anyway just for testing wants to implement it in IFrame.

Comment: So you want the user to interact with the OP in this iframe, or do you want to do a background login in a hidden iframe?

Comment: I want the user to interact with the OP in this iframe. Means I want login form is an iframe, If any implementation you have please let me know

Comment: I've updated my answer to talk more about the iframe for you.

Comment: Hi Andrew is there any kind of example related to this. I am not able to figuring out how to pass IAuthenticationRequest to the iframe.

Comment: Hi Andrew how can I use Javascript for RedirecToProvider.

Comment: Anon., rather than use RedirectToProvider, you have to read the content of OutgoingWebResponse yourself, serialize it for consumption by your javascript, and than have your js do the right thing.  The sample ajaxlogin.aspx includes a demonstration of this, but you'll have to adapt it to your own js if you've written your own.

Answer (score 0):

(In response to Andrew Arnott's response) I'm bothered that popups are considered the norm for redirects.  It's true that Facebook has adopted this approach, but I don't think it's the final solution.  From a UI/UX pov in other applications, we've tried to move away from popup windows in favor of inline types of user experience.  (popup ads, for instance are extremely annoying)  Popups in general are just aggravating.  Hence javascript library third-party widgets such as thickbox/lightbox/shadowbox.  These solutions allow for iframe loaded content.

Plaxo and Google provided an experiment showing something like a 92% return rate for users who signed in with a two click OpenID process, so the question isn't about return rate, and yes popups can work in that scenario, however...

What I think *hasn't* been solved is adoption rate, and this comes down to basic usability and user experience, and what most engineers seem to be missing is the fact that users are completely driven off by popups.

It's true that phishing *is* a problem, but I think the onus and burden for better security lies with the developer on this one, and not the user.  For this reason, I still think an inline experience is best, and, unfortunately, iframes are the only methodology currently employable.  There are solutions, however, to prevent phishing.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are discussing usage of iframes for OP authentication. Have you considered the fact that clickjacking becomes possible when using iframes? In fact, many OPs do not allow their pages to be included in an iframe, e.g. VeriSign, Yahoo, myOpenID, etc. They break out of iframes using the HTTP header `X-FRAME-OPTIONS`,  or JavaScript like this:

if (top.location != location) {
   top.location = self.location;
}

Take a look at http://ajaxian.com/archives/busting-framebusters-clickjacking-is-still-a-big-issue for more information.